# PHP Warning encountered while trying to create a custom WordPress User Registration page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, registration, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've been following a tutorial about how to build a custom wordpress user flow. I'm currently creating a new user registration page and it has this if statement on the page,

```
<?php if ( count( $attributes['errors'] ) > 0 ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $attributes['errors'] as $error ) : ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $error; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the browser this creates and error "Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

I'm 90% sure this is a PHP version issue because I've used this same method on different web hosting and had no problems, but with my hosts I am forced to use version PHP 7.3.30 and I can't switch off PHP warnings.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Its saying that `$attributes['errors']` is not an array, so check it with a simple `var_dump()`

Comment: If you develop code with errors and warnings turned off, you are doing it wrong

Comment: I am not a PHP developer, so I might get it wrong, but IMO it's useless to put the conditional before the loop. If there are no errors, the for loop is not going to do anything anyways...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I checked if $attributes was an array, it was. What was missing is a condition to check if the array is empty, which obviously it is on page load, so, this worked <?php if ( !empty( $attributes['errors'] ) ? count( $attributes['errors'] )+1 : 0 ) : ?>

Comment: Hmm, right. Could not have known that from the amount of code yo shared

Answer (score 0):

So I think I worked out the answer to this question myself.

In newer versions of PHP, when count() is used a condition needs to be set to handle the situation where the array is empty. On page load, in this situation the array is obviously empty, so I changed `<?php if ( count( $attributes['errors'] ) > 0 ) : ?>` to `<?php if ( !empty( $attributes['errors'] ) ? count( $attributes['errors'] )+1 : 0 ) : ?>`

This fixes the problem and now the code works.